# Bulk Check Google Results Count with Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google, excel-online, google-calculator

I need to extract the number of results by a given search in google, for example:

1 I search in Google.es Dinosaurs wallpapers  and it returns to me:

Approximately 77,000,000 results (0.48 seconds)

I need a sheet where i put a search query "dinosaurs wallpapers" and the field on the side counts 77,000,000

| dinosaurs wallpapers | 77,000,000  |

How can i do that?

Thanks in advanced